# PowerShell WebAdministration Module Doesn't Load

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm running into a strange problem, so naturally I came here.  I'm trying to manage 100 or so IIS web servers (2008R2, which are thankfully being tech refreshed, 2012R and 2016).  On several of the servers, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.ProviderNotFoundException: Cannot find a provider with the name
                        'WebAdministration'.
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetProvider(PSSnapinQualifiedName
                        providerName)
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetSingleProvider(String name)
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetNamespaceCurrentLocation(String
                        namespaceID)
                           at System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet.CurrentProviderLocation(String providerId)
                           at Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.IIsCommandBase.ProcessRecord()
                           at Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetConfigurationPropertyCommand.ProcessRecord()
                           at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : WebAdministration
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (WebAdministration:String) [Get-WebConfigurationProperty],
                        ProviderNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderNotFound,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetConfigurationPropertyCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at ConfigureIISLogging,
                        D:\NSI\AutoSPInstaller-master\SP\Automation\AutoSPInstallerModule.psm1: line 3887
                        at Start-Install, D:\NSI\AutoSPInstaller-master\SP\Automation\AutoSPInstallerMain.ps1: line 196
                        at <ScriptBlock>, D:\NSI\AutoSPInstaller-master\SP\Automation\AutoSPInstallerMain.ps1: line 409
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

If I do a Get-PSProvider on one of the servers that ran right through, it shows WebAdministration {IIS}.  This is missing from the servers showing the error.  Most of the time, if I manually import the WebAdministration module, it loads, Get-Command shows all of the commands, but if I try to run one I get `PSProvider Not Found - WebAdministration`.  IIS is installed and running on all servers.  What am I missing?

Comment: What PowerShell version do you use? You can only use that in Windows PowerShell (5.1) or the compatible mode in PowerShell 7.x.

Comment: I'm using 
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1023

Comment: Usually restarting the Powershell session or running it elevated (or not elevated) fixes this sort of issue. However, I do remember seeing this before on 2008 R2 where the issue persisted. I don't think we ever determined the cause before decommissioning the VM. We were at a point where the next logical step was to remove and reinstall IIS, which basically meant rebuilding the server anyways.

Comment: If it was _only_ the 2008 servers I wouldn't care (much), but it happens on some of the 2012 servers also.  That's what's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll") | Out-Null
```

Comment: This appears to work, but doesn't.  It still doesn't show up as a PSProvider.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problems are with permissions, try to run the Powershell as administrator.